# Mysql Category names instead of numbers

Tags: mysql, database, select, group-by, left-join

I take from a database some stuff that work well. The output of the categories is numerically separated with a comma, I am looking for a way to replace these numbers with the corresponding category names.

[image]

The sql statement:

```
    SELECT
    p.products_id as ArtID,
    p.products_model as Artikelnummer,
    p.products_id as ArtID,
    p.products_ean as EAN,
    p.products_sort as "Master Sort",
    p.products_master_slave_order as "Int. Sort",
    d.products_name as Artikelname,
    d.products_short_description as Kurzbeschreibung,
    d.products_description as Beschreibung,
    CONCAT("https://127.0.0.1/",u.url_text) as url_text,
    FORMAT(p.products_vpe_value,0,'de_DE') as products_vpe_value,
    CONCAT(FORMAT(p.products_price,2)," EUR") as "VK Netto",
    FORMAT(p.products_weight,3) as Gewicht,
    p.products_shippingtime as Lieferzeit,
    CONCAT("https://127.0.0.1/media/images/info/",p.products_image) as Bild1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.categories_id ORDER by 'p.products_id' SEPARATOR ',') as Kategorie,
    p.products_status as Status,
    p.disabled_shippings as Spedition,
    d.products_keywords as "Keyword Suche",
    u.meta_title as "Meta Title 55-60",
    u.meta_description as "Meta Description 150"
FROM
    xt_products p
    left join xt_products_description d on p.products_id = d.products_id
    left join xt_products_to_categories c on p.products_id = c.products_id
    left join xt_seo_url u on p.products_id = u.link_id AND u.link_type = 1
GROUP BY p.products_id
ORDER BY `ArtID` ASC
```

The line "GROUP_CONCAT(c.categories_id ORDER by 'p.products_id' SEPARATOR ',') as Kategorie" create the numbers you see in pic. The names of the Categories is in table xt_categories_description > categories_id + categories_name.

Is there a way that instead 784,783,782 can become CatA, CatB, CatC ...

Thank you for help.

Comment: do you have a category table with all the categories alongside their corresponding ID?

Comment: Well step 1 would be to write a  JOIN to the `xt_categories_description` table

Comment: Yes all categories ID and Name

Comment: I have now changed the cat statement to  "GROUP_CONCAT(xcd.categories_name ORDER by 'p.products_id' SEPARATOR ',') as Kategorie" and add "left join xt_categories_description xcd on c.categories_id = xcd.categories_name" this do the job but very slow.

Comment: For performance questions you should include table definitions so we can see the indexes, engine and collation together with an explain plan.